# Hibernate tools Pojo Generation uses Set by default

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, hibernate-tools

Hibernate tools Pojo Generation uses java.util.Set by default. I want to generate POJO's with java.util.List instead of java.util.Set.
Is there any way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Hibernate creates mapping on your database structure. I have one to many mapping without index column so it generates 'Set' which is correct for non indexed one to many mapping.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HBM files, you can use `<bag>` or `<list>` instead of `<set>`

Check Hibernate documentation at : http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/collections.html#collections-mapping